# When upgrading SSD to speed up an Ubuntu VMWare Workstation guest, is either SSD write or read speed more important?

Tags: ssd

On a computer running Windows 8 and hosting Ubuntu 14, should either Read speed or Write speed be the focus when buying an SSD? The main purpose would be to speed up an Ubuntu VM in VMWare workstation. I usually only use the VM for programming in Ruby/Rails.

If there are other things to look for, that would be great too (cache levels, trim, etc.)

When I try to access the VM, sometimes the cursor will lag. Lot's of spinning beach ball icons... Usable most of the time, but not pleasureable.

At http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/ I can toggle to see #1 in Read, write, and other categories.

The VM currently says it has 2.25 DRAM (although this can be toggled, as the host has a max of 8), on a Processor of 2 x 1.05GHz.

I was comparing the 120 GB version and the 240 GB version of the Samsung 840 EVO. Do you think the 240 GB's slightly faster Read/Write speeds will help much for my VM, or is that just a minor difference? I don't need the GB space, just speed. I program every day and want the VM to be faster. http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Samsung-840-Evo-250GB-vs-Samsung-840-Evo-120GB/1594vs1886

Host machine is Acer One 756, 8 GB of Ram (max), Sata 3 6 GB Ram/s, Intel HM70 chipset.

Comment: It's the access latency that counts. Just about any relatively decent SSD would do.

Comment: With 8GiB, paging is unlikely to be the cause of the slowdowns, unless there are KNOWN memory hog applications running.  The obvious solution to speed Ruby/Rails is to run it natively.. dual boot Ubuntu and run applications in WINE (Crossover provide "just works") or thin version of Windows in VM which is less bloated.  If you're serious about development a cheap small box (2nd hand even) can run headless no problem, lets  you login remotely (Putty) & Samba lets Windows PC use network file services.